# NATS local server that provides remote jetstream

Tags: nats.io, nats-jetstream

I want to set up a `NATS` server that listens to a remote `Jetstream` and stores data locally, with the ability to provide this data as another `Jetstream` to its clients.

I tried the mirror option but it requires the remote server to open port 7422 which isn't possible.

An alternative would be to write a program to handle this.

Can some one help me with this?